# Bold the text till it finds $ or (

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell in which there are entity code and names(like E01112 Japan) then the amount(like $2 or ($2)) and then some text (variance is due) and again same pattern in same cell.

E00011 China $56 it is due to rain E00022 Italy ($45) It is due to sun and so on in one cell

I want the entity codes and their name to get bold.

I enter E0 as input and able to bold the entity code but not the entity name.

```
Sub bold_text_start_string()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim counter As Integer
    Set r = Range("c1:c10")
    text_value = InputBox("Please Enter start Text You Want to Search and Bold")
    For Each cell In r
    If InStr(cell.Text, text_value) Then
    cell.Characters(WorksheetFunction.Find(text_value, cell.Value), Len(text_value) + 4).Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use a regular expression to validate your pattern in a cell and then use the match object's properties to start editing your cell. For example:

```
Sub Test()

Dim cl As Range: Set cl = Range("A1")

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\bE\d{5}\b.*?(?=\s*\(?\$)"       
    Set REMatches = .Execute(cl.Value)
    If REMatches.Count > 0 Then
        For Each M In REMatches
            cl.Characters(M.firstindex + 1, M.Length).Font.Bold = True
        Next
    End If 
End With

End Sub
```

The pattern used:

```
\bE\d{5}\b.*?(?=\s*\(?\$)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kTua8b/1)

---

- `\bE\d{5}` - A capital 'E' with 5 trailing digits, between a leading and trailing word-boundary to assert the substring stands alone;
- `.*?` - 0+ (lazy) Characters other than newline;
- `(?=\s*\(?\$)` - Positive lookahead to assert match is followed by 0+ (greedy) whitespace characters, an optional literal open paranthesis and a literal '$'.

---

The above should result in:

> **E00011 China** $56 it is due to rain **E00022 Italy** ($45) It is due to sun and so on in one cell